# Passing values php to kinetic js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, kineticjs

```
var data = {
"images": [
    "img/image1.jpg",
    "img/image2.jpg",
    "img/image3.jpg"
],
"captions":[
    [
        "This is Sample Caption For Image 1",
        "Also This is Sample Caption For Image 1"
    ],
    [
        "This is Sample Caption For Image 2"
    ],
    [
        "This is Sample Caption For Image 3",
        "Also This is Sample Caption For Image 3",
        "And So Does This !"
    ]
]
};

var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;

var stage;
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

function init(config) { }init({"container":"container"});
```

In above kinetic js Where var data = image:[], caption:[] is use i wanted to use image dynamically which is coming from canvas.php, in canvas.php we have php code and now i have to pass image path and captions to above js

Comment: I assume `canvas.php` is a WordPress file (since you've tagged the question).  [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) can be used to pass PHP values to javascript - have you tried that?

Comment: can u plz explain me how this will work as i am new for wordpress

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<script>var img_path = '<?php echo $img_path?>'</script>
```

use this as a global variable holding your values.

now you can use this variable to your `kinetic.js`.